# Changing the SSH client in Git after you've installed it

Tags: git, openssh, ssh-config

Hi We've just started using Git. I went through the install instructions as written down by our Tech support group. I used the defaults they've suggested. However there are certain settings I picked the default for at this time which I might wish to change in the future.

One example would be the SSH client program. The default was to use the bundled OpenSSH client. However I'm using MobaXterm as my current general ssh client and I'd like to stay consistent with my tools.

So how would I be able to switch the SSH client to be MobaXterm after I've already installed Git with it's default settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables [`GIT_SSH` or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode) to point to the program of preference.

A necessary precondition is that the program uses one of the command line interface variants that Git understands, see [`GIT_SSH_VARIANT`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHVARIANTcode).

Comment: [`git config core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand), [`git config ssh.variant`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sshvariant).

Comment: So, there is no config file or other setting that was set when git was installed?  The Git installer asked which SSH to use, and I selected to use the existing one - which was an incorrect choice.
There is no way to just switch it back to the other choice without uninstalling and re-installing git?

Comment: @CasaDelGato If you are talking about the Git for Windows installer, then I think the way to use "the existing one" is that no Git for Windows-owned SSH is installed. I think you have to re-install Git for Windows. No guarantees, though. I don't use Git for Windows.